# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel flutter_email_sender)

Tags: firebase, email, flutter-web

Sending mail from Flutter Web. Trying to send email with security code to recipient email input in the TextFormField.

```
import 'package:flutter_email_sender/flutter_email_sender.dart';

 final Email email = Email(
      body: _bodyController.text,
      subject: _subjectController.text,
      recipients: [_recipientController.text],
      attachmentPaths: attachments,
      isHTML: isHTML,
    );

    String platformResponse;

    try {
      await FlutterEmailSender.send(email);
      platformResponse = 'success';
    } catch (error) {
      platformResponse = error.toString();
    }

    if (!mounted) return;

    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: Text(platformResponse),
      ),
    );
```

pubspec.yaml

```
flutter_email_sender: ^5.0.2
```

The error got:

```
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel flutter_email_sender)
```

The problem remains the same after Invalidate Caches/Restart.
Does anyone know how to solve to this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Rebuild it instead of hot restart/hot reload

Comment: Great. Rebuild solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the `flutter_email_sender` plugin is not supported for the web platform.

The displayed error message `MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method send on channel flutter_email_sender)` indicates that.

All packages available in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) have some tags that indicates the supported platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following

- Execute `flutter run` since you changed the pubspec.yml
- Rebuild it instead of hot restart/hot reload
- If that doesn't work, try `flutter clean`